# How to get Ethereum internal transaction list / contract transaction list by RPC?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, ether

How to get Ethereum internal transaction list / contract transaction list by RPC ?

Contract: 0xa5025faba6e70b84f74e9b1113e5f7f4e7f4859f
How to get the contract address transaction list by RPC ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZkyp.png)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is iterate through the blockchain and check each transaction in each block for a transaction that you are describing. While this will work (with a bit of code), you are better off reading the data from an existing block explorer. By doing it on your own, you will be creating a limited-functionality block explorer, when you should be using other resources.

Take a look at the [Etherscan APIs](https://etherscan.io/apis), as they contain all the data you need.